# how to add long svg code to html in some good ways

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, svg

On my website, I am adding some SVG animations so I have to add big SVG code with id tags to animate. So, the problem is the SVG code is taking 400 to 500 lines of my HTML code. So how can I add SVG code with id tags in some shorter way or compact way.

Comment: Just create seperate `.svg` file and import it in html file using `<img id='my-id' src='file.svg'>` tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create separate ***.svg*** file and import it where needed using

```
<img id='some-id' src='file-name.svg'>
```

Comment: Can I use the same ways in the js file too. to animate the SVG with id

Comment: Could you explain what you mean ?

Comment: Ok, so I want to animate different parts of the SVG image (diff. parts have diff ID tags) with GSAP js. And till now I have added all the SVG code to my HTML and add animation in different parts. so the question here is can I use getElementById to select different ID's. when I use <img id='some-id' src='file-name.svg'>

Comment: Yes, that should be possible.

Comment: https://codepen.io/GreenSock/pen/PqbWmZ

Nice example